# OpenGL not working after kernel update (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, kernel, opengl

Few days ago a got kernel update to ver. **3.13.0.74**. When PC has been restarted I seen 600x800 resolution and OpenGL didn't work.
When I reboot with old kernel **3.13.0.71** everything works fine!
Why this issue appeared, and how to set boot only with old kernel?

(Ubuntu 12.04 x64, nVidia 210 with 331.110 driver)

Comment: Did you try to (re) install the video drivers on the new kernel? It might be that something went wrong with DKMS. What was the update output saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, reinstalling drivers from .run file fix it (from repository it has some issues for Nvidia-210). Will I need reinstall driver eveytime after next kernel updates?